# Is it possible to move already fetched swift packages across to another computer?

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

I have an Xcode project that contains swift packages that have all been fetched.
I wish to open this same Xcode project on a different computer that doesn't have internet.
I have moved the project directory across.
Is it possible to move the swift packages across to prevent needing to re-fetch the swift packages? And if so, what directories do I need to move across?

Answer (score 0):

Look in your DerivedData under YourApp > SourcePackages > checkouts. Behold, there are your downloaded packages. Copy them to the other machine and add them manually to the project as local packages.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @matt. "and add them manually to the project as local packages" does this mean that SPM isn't smart enough to see them as already fetched packages? And instead it needs to treat them as local packages?

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it too. If you have no Internet connection how can anything be "fetched"?

Comment: So before attempting to fetch the package, Xcode would check if the packages are already in the cache. If they are and match the `package.resolved`, then no need to fetch. I'm asking if SPM is smart enough to do that, thus avoiding the need to "add them manually to the project as local packages."

Comment: Well, real programmers try stuff; so try it. I've told you where it needs to go (in DerivedData) in order to be seen as having been downloaded. But I strongly doubt just slotting it into that spot will work; that's why I suggest adding it yourself.

Comment: Sure, I'll give it a go soon. I'd be surprised if it doesn't work. It seems to be the same as if I was on a machine with internet, fetched all the packages, closed Xcode, moved out all the packages in DerivedData, went out and bought "iOS 15 Programming Fundamentals with Swift", came back and put the packages back in their original spot.

Comment: The reason my instinct is to doubt that it will work is that I suspect there is a lot more bookkeeping going on than just the mere presence of the packages in the DerivedData.